# How to borrow but keep

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a big struct, for instance `Vec<i32>`.
Now my code looks like

```
fn main() {
    let mut arr = vec![0, 1, 2];
    // Lot of code pre
    arr.push(5);
    // Lot of code post
    println!("{:?}", arr);
}
```

I want to take the piece out so it would look like

```
fn main() {
    let mut arr = vec![0, 1, 2];
    my_push(arr, 5);
    println!("{:?}", arr);
}

fn my_push(mut arr: Vec<i32>, x: i32) {
    // Lot of code
    arr.push(x);
    // Lot of code
}
```

How to implement it right for the cases? I need just to take the piece into separate function.
I get error because arr is moved to `my_push` and there it is destroyed.

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `arr`
 --> src/main.rs:4:22
  |
2 |     let mut arr = vec![0, 1, 2];
  |         ------- move occurs because `arr` has type `Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
3 |     my_push(arr, 5);
  |             --- value moved here
4 |     println!("{:?}", arr);
  |                      ^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

Comment: Maybe what you want is to take a mutable *reference* for `my_push`, not **assume ownership**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by passing in a mutable reference, as right now you're handing over ownership of that to the function, whereupon it's just dropped, never to be seen again.

Consider this alteration:

```
fn main() {
    let mut arr : Vec<i32>  = vec![0, 1, 2];

    // Use a mutable reference to a mutable local
    my_push(&mut arr, 5);

    // Local array has been mutated
    println!("{:?}", arr);
}

fn my_push(arr: &mut Vec<i32>, x: i32) {
    // Here arr behaves largely like it's a local variable,
    // except for some minor restrictions like not being able
    // to move it.
    arr.push(x);
}
```

Remember that Rust takes ownership very seriously. If you're used to languages like Python, JavaScript or Ruby where passing in array like this is always done as an implicit reference, that is absolutely not the case in Rust. References *must* be explicit, as in `&` or `&mut`.